# Escape key press not working with second modal window in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-directives

I have a table with multiple rows, each row has a button, on clicking the button, a modal window opens contains form element.

After submitting the form, second window opens for confirmation and first window closes.

Below code is my sample work flow.

**My problem is**

*On Escape* key press, works when the first window was opened but not able to close the second window when it was opened.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button @click="openFormWindow">Open form</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <modal v-on-escape="hideFirstModal" v-if="isFirstWindowOpen">
            <div>
                <form @submit="submitFormOne">
                    <input type="text">
                    <button type="submit"></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </modal>
        <modal v-on-escape="hideSecondModal" v-if="isSecondWindowOpen">
            <p>confirmation window</p>
        </modal>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            isFirstWindowOpen: false,
            isSecondWindowOpen: false
        }
    }
    methods: {
        openFormWindow () {
            // form window opens 
            this.isFirstWindowOpen = true
        },
        hideFirstModal () {
            this.isFirstWindowOpen = false
        },
        hideSecondModal () {
            this.isSecondWindowOpen = false
        },
        submitFormOne () {
            // submit the details, let the first window close & open the second window.
            this.isFirstWindowOpen = false
            this.isSecondWindowOpen = true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

vue directive `on-escape`

```
Vue.directive('on-escape', {
    bind (el, binding, vnode) {
        el.customEventKeydown = function (event) {
            // Check if click was outside the el and his childrens
            if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                vnode.context[binding.expression](event)
            }
        }
        document.body.addEventListener("keydown", el.customEventKeydown)
    },
    unbind (el) {
        document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", el.customEventKeydown)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `key` on each `<modal>` component to tell Vue not to reuse DOM nodes:

```html
<modal v-on-escape="hideFirstModal" v-if="isFirstWindowOpen" key="modal1">
```

```html
<modal v-on-escape="hideSecondModal" v-if="isSecondWindowOpen" key="modal2">
```

Vue was reusing the DOM for the first modal when it created the 2nd, so the second `keydown` event listener was never created.

When elements are added and removed from the DOM, Vue sometimes tries to help by reusing old DOM nodes to speed up rendering.  Sometimes this can have unwanted side effects.  The `key` essentially instructs it not to do this.

Comment: there are some advantages and disadvantages in using vue vs pure vanilla js, thanks for ur help dude.

Comment: Only advantages!  :)   The DOM reuse thing is an easy snag to fall into when creating directives or anything that manipulates the DOM manually, if using 2+ of the same element sequentially.  You're welcome bud

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `this.isSecondWindowOpen`, it isn't being returned in your data function.

Comment: oh yeah but here i forgot to add

Comment: i updated the code, can u pls remove your answer

Comment: Firstly, can you try adding `@keydown.esc="hideFirstModal"` and same for your second modal and see if that works. Secondly try adding a tab index to each modal element. (e.g. tabindex="0")